# C# client fails to call Axis2 Java web service

Tags: c#, web-services, apache-axis

I have a Axis2 built Java web service which works fine with Soap UI and using CXF/Axis client. I also need to make it work with .Net/C# client built using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

When I try to make a call using the service through Microsoft Visual Studio client it fails.

Please see the Visual Studio code : -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService.NameWorldwideService;

namespace ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HIqualityNameWorldwidePortTypeClient client = new HIqualityNameWorldwidePortTypeClient();
            validateFamilyNameRequest req = new validateFamilyNameRequest();
            req.input = "Kumar";
            req.maxNumberOfSuggestions = 2;
            DetailedNameResult res = client.validateFamilyName("Kumar",null,2);

        }
    }
}
```

Exception on client side: -

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException was
>   unhandled   Message="unknown"
>   Source="mscorlib"   StackTrace:
>       Server stack trace: 
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          at ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService.NameWorldwideClient.HIqualityNameWorldwidePortType.interpret(interpretRequest
>   request)
>          at ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService.NameWorldwideClient.HIqualityNameWorldwidePortTypeClient.ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService.NameWorldwideClient.HIqualityNameWorldwidePortType.interpret(interpretRequest
>   request) in
>   c:\work\consumenameworldwidewebservice\consumenameworldwidewebservice\service
>   references\nameworldwideclient\reference.cs:line
>   1131
>          at ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService.Form1.button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\work\ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService\ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService\Form1.cs:line
>   33
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&
>   m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&
>   msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32
>   pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService.Program.Main()
>   in
>   C:\work\ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService\ConsumeNameWorldwideWebService\Program.cs:line
>   18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Exception on Server Side: -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.jav
>   a:194)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
>   (RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
>   sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
>   ssageReceiver.java:114)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
>   uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:1
>   42)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
>   icationFilterChain.java:269)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   ilterChain.java:188)
>           at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:129)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
> ```
>
> icationFilterChain.java:215)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   ilterChain.java:188)
>           at com.hi.openname.filter.OpenNameFilter.doFilter(OpenNameFilter.java:46
>   )
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
>   icationFilterChain.java:215)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   ilterChain.java:188)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
>   alve.java:213)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
>   alve.java:172)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
>   ava:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
>   ava:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
>   ve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
>   a:174)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
>   :873)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.p
>   rocessConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpo
>   int.java:528)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFol
>   lowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadP
>   ool.java:689)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   2011-02-20 15:31:34,837
>   [http-8080-Processor25] ERROR
>   AxisEngine -
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
>           at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
>   (RPCMessageReceiver.java:161)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
>   sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
>   ssageReceiver.java:114)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
>   uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:1
>   42)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
>   icationFilterChain.java:269)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   ilterChain.java:188)
>           at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:129)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
> ```
>
> icationFilterChain.java:215)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   ilterChain.java:188)
>           at com.hi.openname.filter.OpenNameFilter.doFilter(OpenNameFilter.java:46
>   )
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
>   icationFilterChain.java:215)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
>   ilterChain.java:188)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
>   alve.java:213)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
>   alve.java:172)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
>   ava:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
>   ava:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
>   ve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
>   a:174)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
>   :873)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.p
>   rocessConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpo
>   int.java:528)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFol
>   lowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadP
>   ool.java:689)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.jav
>   a:194)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
>   (RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
>           ... 27 more

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your wsdl?  C# and Axis2 sometimes interpret wsdls slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought: shouldn't you pass the Request object like so:

```
HIqualityNameWorldwidePortTypeClient client = new HIqualityNameWorldwidePortTypeClient();
    validateFamilyNameRequest req = new validateFamilyNameRequest();
    req.input = "Kumar";
    req.maxNumberOfSuggestions = 2;
    DetailedNameResult res = client.validateFamilyName(req);
```

Instead of passing the params separately as you do now?

Comment: Yes you are right but even with that is breaks with the exceptions I attached.